# nested one to many serializer model django

Tags: django

```
I am trying to create a relationship between databases
```

result : =>

[
{
"id":1,
"title":"mobile",
"category_two":[
{
"id":3,
"title":"brand"
},
{
"id":4,
"title":"memory"
}
]
}
]

and i expect : =>

[
{
"id":1,
"title":"mobile",
"category_two":[
{
"id":3,
"title":"brand",
"category_three":[
{
"id":1,
"title":"samsung"
},
{
"id":2,
"title":"apple"
}
]
},
{
"id":4,
"title":"memory",
"category_three":[
{
"id":1,
"title":"32gb"
},
{
"id":2,
"title":"64gb"
}
]
}
]
}
]

```
// views
class get_Category(APIView):
        def get(self, request):
            category = CategoryOne.objects.all()
            serializer = CategoryTwoSerializer(category, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

```
//serializers

class CategoryOneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryOne
        fields = '__all__'

class CategoryTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_two= CategoryOneSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryTwo
        fields = '__all__'
        depth=5
        

class CategoryThreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_three = CategoryTwoSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryThree
        fields = '__all__'
        depth=5
```

```
// models
class CategoryOne(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class CategoryTwo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categoryone = models.ForeignKey(CategoryOne,related_name='category_two',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class CategoryThree(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categorytwo = models.ForeignKey(CategoryTwo,related_name='category_three',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class CategoryOneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_two= CategoryTwoSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryOne
        fields = '__all__'

class CategoryTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_three = CategoryThreeSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryTwo
        fields = '__all__'

class CategoryThreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryThree
        fields = '__all__'

// views
class get_Category(APIView):
        def get(self, request):
            category = CategoryOne.objects.prefetch_related("category_two", "category_two__category_three")
            serializer = CategoryOneSerializer(category, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

If you want category_two rows related to a specific category_one to be serialized with it, you essentially want to add a non existing data to CategoryOne.
Since means you need two add it to the serializer and specify how to serialize it.

Here you can access this data by using a related_name, therefore adding a field with the proper related_name will suffice for django to find the data you want.
The same wan be done the serializer CategoryThree tied the a specific CategoryTwo row.

Howerver doing this will produce a LOT of SQL queries since each time my_category_on.category_two.all() is called by the serializer, an sql query is needed.
The `prefetch_related()` is here to solve the issue